# Third-party plugin that changes host's menu in Win32

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, mfc

I am working on 3rd-party plugin for a desktop Windows app. It is basically a traditional DLL that is only ever accessed by the host application. The host provides menu items for the plugin, based on an API, but I would like to extend the API by modifying the text of my menu items dynamically based on which file is open. The host uses an MDI window and I think it is developed with MFC. However, I am attempting to change the menu items directly with the Win API. (This may be the problem right there, which is part of my question.)

The code works correctly the first time I change the menu item. But subsequent changes do not appear on the menu. The weird thing is that GetMenuString seems always to return the value I set it to. That means that on the API level it appears to work, but the menu items do not change (except for the first time).

Here is the code I use to change the menu item text. It's very basic.

```
MENUITEMINFOW menuInfo;
memset ( &menuInfo, 0, sizeof(menuInfo) );
menuInfo.cbSize = sizeof(menuInfo);
menuInfo.fMask = MIIM_STRING;
menuInfo.fType = MFT_STRING;
menuInfo.dwTypeData = (LPWSTR)newItemText;
SetMenuItemInfoW (hMenu, idToChange, false, &menuInfo);
```

Could MFC be interfering with this? Or perhaps an idiosyncrasy of the host app's menu handling? Or is there something else I need to do to get the menu to display correctly?

Comment: Maybe the host is owner-drawing the menu items and is ignoring (or not detecting) your custom text changes since you are bypassing the host's API? How are you adding your menu items to the host's menu in the first place?

Comment: The host requests the text for each menu item at startup.

Comment: The most likely answer is that the host is owner-drawing the menu items or caching them some other way. I posted the question in hopes I might be wrong.

Comment: Since you have not provided any information about the host app or the plugin API it exposes, there is no way to answer that for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by using DeleteMenu and InsertMenu instead of SetMenuItemInfo. The code is straigthforward, but here it is in case it helps someone else like me.

```
const UINT idToChange = GetMenuItemID ( hMenu, index );
DeleteMenu ( hMenu, index, MF_BYPOSITION );
InsertMenuW ( hMenu, index, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, idToChange, (LPWSTR)newItemText );
```